# Has mental health deteriorated 1000-fold since 1850?

Tags: psychiatry

In the standard “things are worse now than ever before” polemic, it's claimed that rates of mental illness are higher now than ever – usually without any proof, and usually alongside known-false claims such as people now being more violent or less healthy (compared to, say, the 1400s).

It seems clear that rates of *diagnosis* are on the rise, as are disability claims. But can't this just be due to lowered thresholds for diagnosis, and more people seeking treatment? Are there studies that show incidence actually increasing, or an upward trend in psychiatric assessment scores?

**EDIT:**

Although I've heard this most often amid a laundry list of unsourced (mostly known-false) claims, here's [an article](http://www.cchr.org/sites/default/files/Anatomy_of_an_Epidemic_Psychiatric_Drugs_Rise_of_Mental_Illness.pdf) in Spring 2005's *Ethical Human Psychology and Psychiatry* which was later expanded into [the book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomy_of_an_Epidemic) discussed [here](http://www.counterpunch.org/2010/04/28/the-astonishing-rise-of-mental-illness-in-america/). It claims that mental illness per 1000 went from 0.2 in 1850 to 20 in 2003.

What I'm looking for in an answer is:

- Historic prevalences of a few mental disorders with *very* well-defined symptoms,
- A good proxy for mental health (e.g., attempted suicide) over at least 50 years, or
- Repeated applications of a psychiatric assessment scale to groups of people “picked up off the street” at intervals over a total of 25 years or more (*not* a cohort study; a different group every time).

Comment: How prevalent can a condition be if we cannot diagnose it?

Comment: If one took current diagnostic criteria for a disease and applied them to random populations at different points in history, what would the trend look like?

Comment: Possible dupe of: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/195/is-there-an-autism-epidemic

Comment: Okay. If the question's too broad to answer, I really could just do with a meta-study of the Global Assessment Scale or the Chapman Scales or anything similar applied to random, man-off-the-street samples over a period of maybe 25 years. That's what I was looking for in the first place, but I never found it and figured that I might as well aim higher over here.

Comment: Welcome to Skeptics! Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim is being made. Also, please support your statement that "diagnosis rates" are up. I am not an expert in the field and have no reason to believe they are higher now than, say, the 1980s.

Comment: An example: 20-years ago a person saying *"I don't feel like working"* would be considered lazy, today that person is considered *"suffering from depression"*.

Comment: *people now being more violent or less healthy (compared to, say, the 1400s).*. Have you really ever read a claim saying we are less healthy than in the 1400s? That would be quite a claim.

Comment: @nico: for example old-age diseases were practically unknown in 1400s ;-)

Comment: @vartec: no doubt about that!

Comment: @vartec the way depression is defined is uncontrollable crying typically in somewhere like the work place.

Comment: Isn't a lot of 'increase' because these mental health' events are being recorded much more reliably and where the case isn't particularly extreme.

Answer (score 4):

Answer: It's rarely as simple as that.

You suggest picking a couple of diseases.

Well, we have already seen that the story for [Autism](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/195/is-there-an-autism-epidemic) is far more complicated than just measuring diagnoses per 1000 people.

I figured [epilepsy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epilepsy) would be a good example of a mental disorder with fairly well-defined symptoms.

- Sander JW., [The epidemiology of epilepsy revisited.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12644744), Curr Opin Neurol. 2003 Apr;16(2):165-70.

First, Professor Sander explains that prevalence depends on whether you are in developed or resource-poor countries. So, there's the first confounding factor.

Second, there are other geographical factors:

> There is geographic variation in the incidence of epileptic syndromes likely to be associated with genetic and environmental factors, although as yet causality has not been fully established.

So, that (combined with immigration) is going to make the figures difficult to understand.

Then, he explains that the *age groups* of the incidences have changed ("a decrease in younger age groups and an increase in persons above 60 years") over time.

But is this just because the population is getting older so the numbers of diagnoses in that age has increased? A poll of people from the street might give a totally misleading result.

In conclusion: There are many different factors that make the underlying question much more complicated than it sounds. Simply asking "Has the number of diagnoses gone up?" doesn't answer anything unless you control for many, many confounding variables like:

- Population's age
- Population's immigration
- Population's wealth
- Diagnostic techniques (which you did try to control for in the question)
- Stigma/support attached to diagnosis.
- etc.

Comment: I've never thought of epilepsy as a mental illness before. http://www.pni.org/neuropsychiatry/seizures/epilepsy/epilepsy_psychiatry.html says that it's "predominantly neurologic and not psychiatric condition".

Comment: @Gabe, oh! I don't deny that epilepsy is neurological (and I am not suggesting it clouds the thoughts of sufferers at any time outside of an attack), but I had always interpreted mental illness to include neurological conditions. If the more common understanding (especially by @rdhs) is that this isn't the case, I'll delete my answer. What's the consensus?

Comment: I do believe that rdhs was referencing an article that talks about illnesses that are generally treated with antipsychotics. However, the fact that epilepsy is not treated with such drugs doesn't necessarily invalidate your answer. I'd rather see you change *epilepsy* to *schizophrenia* or *depression* rather than delete your answer.

Comment: Yeah, my first thought for the "specific illness" route was catatonic schizophrenia – something someone would look at and say, "Wow, that person snapped; this is a symptom of a sick society." But for some reason this answer *did* get me looking at the WHO's US suicide statistics: There's been a 50% rise in the past 50 years, but it's not the 900% (!) suggested, and the rise reflects mostly our aging population and the closing gender gap. If anybody could get the statistics for *attempted* suicide and take those back to 1850, that'd be an answer. Or else maybe I could get around to it...

Comment: I was afraid schizophrenia and depression diagnosis criteria may have changed, making it more complex to compare.